# Getting from Sarajevo airport to city centre?

Tags: airport-transfer, bosnia, sjj

Are there straightforward, easy public transport connections between the airport and the city? Or would you recommend a taxi?

Googling around, there's a lot of dated information. And [Wikitravel suggests](https://wikitravel.org/en/Sarajevo) the bus (103) might be a bit of a hassle (not actually departing from the airport). Recent first-hand experiences would be especially appreciated.

Comment: My old copy of LP Eastern Europe (2007) says: "Taxi (20KM) is the quickest way to town but a cheaper alternative is to take the taxi to Ilidža (5KM) and transfer to tram 3 for Baščaršija." I might try the tram; the [network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trams_in_Sarajevo#/media/File:Sarajevo_tramway_network_map.svg) looks straightforward indeed ;)

Comment: Taxis are inexpensive but on at least one occasion, maybe 5 years ago, I've seen the drivers in the airport trying to gouge visitors.  You could try calling Samir i Emir or Crveni Taxi.

Answer (score 1):

City buses 36, 37, 45 and 47 stop at the airport. Information on their routings is really poor though, but you need to travel in the direction of the left (from your POV when exiting the airport), and ask for the closest tram stop ("tramvajski stajalishte").

From the closest tram stop, catch tram 3, 4 or 6 to wherever you need to be.

Alternatively, a simpler option is catching a taxi (Crveni taxi is recommended - NEVER take Sarajevo taxi, which, although the best option in the city in general, is legit mafia at the airport) to the Stup tram stop, from where trams 3, 4 and 6 run to the centre. Make sure the driver uses the meter - if not, insist on it.